# extract a random sample of a table where a unique combination of two columns are not associated with a value

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table of clients in the following format

```
client_firstname  client_lastname  fruit    purchase_date
Lionel            Messi            apples   11/11/2020
Lionel            Messi            bananas  11/13/2020
Federico          Chiesa           oranges  11/20/2020
.
.
.
```

I want to create a random subset of 10000 first name,lastname pairs who never bought apples and extract all the entries associated with them.

so far I have:

```
select t.*
from client_table t
where exists (select 1
       from client_table t2
       where t2.firstname = t.firstname and
       t2.lastname = t.lastname
       t2.fruit <> "apples")
```

I know it is possible to create a second table with:

```
select distinct client_table.firstname, client_table.lastname
where table.fruit <> "apples"
order by rand() limit 10000
```

but is it possible to include this table in the `where exists` statement and avoid creating a second table?

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> who never bought apples

This:

```
  exists (...
       t2.fruit <> "apples")
```

..does not meet the specification. The code is "people who bought something that is not an apple", not "people who never bought an apple"

This gives you non-apple-buyers:

```
select t.*
from client_table t
where not exists (select 1
       from client_table t2
       where t2.firstname = t.firstname and
       t2.lastname = t.lastname
       t2.fruit = 'apples')
```

But I don't think I'd do it this way, because that list will contain duplicates

Instead let's ask for the unique list of people that haven't bought apples:

```
select firstname, lastname
from client_table 
group by firstname, lastname
having sum(case when fruit = 'apples' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

Then you can add your order by/limit onto that, and if you need more data from the table, turn it into a subquery and join it back to the main table

```
select t.*
from 
 client_table t 
 inner join
 (
  select firstname, lastname
  from client_table 
  group by firstname, lastname
  having sum(case when fruit = 'apples' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
 ) x on x.firstname = t.firstname and x.lastname = t.lastname
```